# Bootstrap datepicker add duration to End Date issue when using variable value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have the following code. It's working fine if I use some values but when I passing value from variable(var duration) its showing wrong result.

```js
$('#startdate, #enddate').datepicker({
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  autoclose: true,
});

$('#duration').change(function() {
  var date2 = $('#startdate').datepicker('getDate');
  var duration = $(this).val();
  //alert(duration);
  date2 = new Date(date2);
  date2.setMonth(date2.getMonth() + duration);
  $('#enddate').datepicker('setDate', date2);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="startdate" id="startdate">
<select name="duration" id="duration">
  <option>Select month</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="36">36</option>
</select>
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="enddate" id="enddate">
```

Comment: try var duration = parseInt($(this).val());

Comment: Example

Set the month to 4 (May) and the day to the 20th:
             var d = new Date(); 
             d.setMonth(4, 20);

The result of d will be: 
               Fri May 20 2016 11:25:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make integer parsing to you duration variable.

```
var duration = parseInt($(this).val());
```

That's all

Comment: This also works `date2.setMonth((date2.getMonth()) + (+duration));`